# Help with Regex expression required

Tags: javascript, regex

I am hoping someone can help me find a suitable regex expression in javascript that meets the requirement of the statement below. I have tried a few expressions but including an asterisk character as a character literal in the search complicates things.

> Given string str, match and replace all occurences of an asterisk character with the correct escape sequence to treat it as a character literal, but ignore any asterisk character contained in a sequence like this in the string: <*>

Any help, much appreciated.
Danie

Comment: What expressions have you tried?

Comment: Give us some examples of what you want to match and what you don't want to match (and what you have tried of course;) )

Comment: Sounds like you are asking us to do your homework or a job interview assignment for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var x='xx**<*>*><*<*>>>*';
    x=x.replace(/(<)?\*(>)?/g, function($0, $1 ,$2){

        return $1 ? $2 ? $0 : 'y' : $2 ? 'y' : 'y';
});
alert(x);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yDT25/

Answer (score 0):

If it's exactly the `<*>` sequence that you have to avoid replacing `*` in (and you are using PCRE or the like) then you can use something like:
`/(?<!<)\*(?!>)/`

Comment: javascript doesnt support lookbehinds

Comment: damn js, didn't notice the tag.